# Titlepane children set the parent delayed

Tags: javafx

The children of the titlepane set their parent (the titlepane) very late. Not like any other ui element I used. Example Code:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Group root = new Group();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 275);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    VBox vbox = new VBox(new Circle(30, Color.RED));
    TitledPane titledPane = new TitledPane("circle", vbox);
    root.getChildren().add(titledPane);
    System.out.println(titledPane.getParent());//parent is set
    System.out.println(vbox.getParent());//parent not set
}
```

While the vbox has his parent set immediately, the titlepane has not. Is this behaviour wanted (as effect of the framework) or really just inconsistent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that with the `VBox` you are placing it in a `Control`. It is not added to the actual control, but to its skin (or part of the structure created by the skin), and that is not constructed until it is actually physically displayed. A similar thing will happen if, for example, you set a node as the graphic for a label:

```
Label l = new Label();
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(10, 10);
l.setGraphic(rect);
System.out.println(rect.getParent());
```

The general rule is that if you call

```
parent.getChildren().add(node);
```

then `node.getParent()` will immediately be set to `parent`. If you call a different method, such as `titledPane.setContent(...)`, `label.setGraphic(...)`, or `splitPane.getItems().add(...)`, then the node's parent will not be changed until the control is displayed.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this updated example which (I think) helps demonstrate what is going on (which is already explained in James' answer):

The output of the sample is:

```
Showing an empty scene with no content
Adding some content
Parent of node added directly to a child of a scene graph node: Group@27d5d559[styleClass=root]
Parent of node added only as content to a control: null
Manually requesting CSS application and a layout pass
Detected vbox parent changed to TitledPaneSkin$1@7cf1d24e[styleClass=content]
Parent of node added only as content to a control after triggering css and layout: TitledPaneSkin$1@7cf1d24e[styleClass=content]
```

As you can see, manually triggering a CSS application and layout pass will end up instantiating and initializing the the control's skin, which will place the node added as content to the control into the scene graph and wire up the node's parent.  In general though, be careful about manually triggering CSS and layout passes as that can have a negative performance impact if you do it a lot - in a case like this simple sample, the performance impact would be completely negligible.

---

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TitledPanSample extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 275);
        stage.setScene(scene);

        System.out.println("Showing an empty scene with no content");
        stage.show();

        System.out.println("Adding some content");

        VBox vbox = new VBox(new Circle(30, Color.RED));
        vbox.parentProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            System.out.println("Detected vbox parent changed to " + newValue);
        });

        TitledPane titledPane = new TitledPane("circle", vbox);
        root.getChildren().add(titledPane);
        System.out.println("Parent of node added directly to a child of a scene graph node: " + titledPane.getParent());//parent is set
        System.out.println("Parent of node added only as content to a control: " + vbox.getParent());//parent not set

        System.out.println("Manually requesting CSS application and a layout pass");
        root.applyCss();
        root.layout();

        System.out.println("Parent of node added only as content to a control after triggering css and layout: " + vbox.getParent());//parent is set
    }
}
```